# Sum of dependent random variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed in such a way that $X\sim U[-1,1]$ and $Y\sim U[-|X|,|X|]$.

I am interested in obtaining the PDF of $X+Y$ using Mathematica.

Without much hope, I tried the following

```
c := TransformedDistribution[
  u + v, {u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}], 
   v \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-u, u}]}]
```

which did not work (among other things, the resulting `PDF[c]` has two variables).

*Beyond this relatively simple example that can be solved with pen and paper, how can one use Mathematica to obtain the PDF of the sum of two random variables when the (conditional) distribution of one depends on the realization of the other?*

Comment: You've given the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ given $X$.  What you need is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to proceed.  That question is better asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @JimB: Thanks for your comment. I see your point. I guess I was trying to provide a concrete example of something I'd like to know how to do more generally in Mathematica, i.e., get the distribution of the sum of two random variables when a parameter of the second depends on the realization of the first. I understand that this can be done with pen and paper in the relatively easy case I am provided here. Isn't it legitimate though to wonder how to do it in Mathematica, even when an pen-and-paper solution is available? I've edited my question to reflect this comment.

Comment: Your $Y\sim U[-X,X]$.is not correctly defined: think of negative values of  $X\sim U[-1,1]$ .

Comment: @user64494.  Yes and no.  Probably $Y\sim U(-\mid X \mid),\mid X \mid)$ should be used.  However, in *Mathematica* `UniformDistribution[{1,-1}]` works just fine.

Comment: @FZS With your edit for the reason to solve that problem, I agree.

Comment: @JimB: Your statement "However, in Mathematica UniformDistribution[{1,-1}] works just fine " does not correspond to reality in view of PDF[UniformDistribution[{1, -1}], t] which outputs "UniformDistribution::lss: Parameter 1 at position {1,1} in UniformDistribution[{1,-1}] is expected to be less than -1".

Comment: @user64494.  Yep, I overstated things.  I only checked out `RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{1, -1}], 10]` which does work fine.  Reality just isn't what it used to be.

Comment: @JimB: This is a bug in RandomVariate up to the documentation "UniformDistribution allows min and max to be any real numbers with min<max".

Comment: @user64494: Thanks, made an edit (I think regardless of what works and doesn't in Mathematica, $Y\sim U[-|X|,|X|]$ is a mathematical statement, not a piece of code, so it should be well-defined and user64494 is right to call me out on this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct any distribution from *pdf*s of other distributions with `ProbabilityDistribution`, and `Method -> "Normalize"` will normalize it:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
         PDF[UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}], u] PDF[UniformDistribution[{-Abs[u], Abs[u]}], v]
       , {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, Method -> "Normalize"];

pdf = PDF@TransformedDistribution[u + v, {u, v} \[Distributed] dist]
```

Comment: `pdf` is a joint density but it is not the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ nor is it the univariate density of the sum of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: +1 Your edit fixed things.

Comment: @JimB You're right, just needed some basic probability knowledge refreshment :)

Comment: `Method -> "Normalize"` doesn't work in v10.1; is it strictly necessary here?  What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It ensures that the resulting distribution is valid, so that it integrates to 1 over its domain. It's straightforward to do integration separately and normalize it too. In this particular case it doesn't matter though, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 8):

This particular problem can be completely performed with *Mathematica* without resorting to paper and pencil.

The joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is given by the product of the marginal density of $X$ (which is $1\over2$) and the conditional density of $Y\mid X$ (which is $1\over{2\mid X \mid}$):

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{(1/2)*(1/(2 Abs[x]), -1 <= x <= 1 && Abs[y] <= Abs[x] && x != 0},
   {∞, x == 0}}, 0]
```

Apply `ProbabilityDistribution` on the joint density:

```
d = ProbabilityDistribution[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Abs[x], Abs[x]}]
```

[image: Distribution of X and Y]

Now find the distribution of $Z=X+Y$:

```
dz = TransformedDistribution[x + y, {x, y} \[Distributed] d];
pdf = PDF[dz, z]
```

[image: Density of sum of X and Y]

```
Plot[pdf, {z, -2.5, 2.5}]
```

[image: Plot of density function]

The expression of the pdf can be simplified to

```
pdf = Piecewise[{{Log[2/Abs[z]]/4, -2 < z < 2}}, 0]
```

[image: Short version of pdf]

Comment: This is done rather by hand with the help of Mathematica.

Comment: @user64494.  Yes, I didn't see an a approach that would do that kind of simplification.  My feeble attempts using `FullSimplify` and `PiecewiseExpand` didn't provide any simplication.

Comment: The result of s = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}], 10^5];t = Flatten[ Map[# + RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-RealAbs[#], RealAbs[#]}], 1] &, s]];Histogram[t, 40] confirms  your answer answer.

Answer (score 8):

This becomes quite straight forward if we note that `y` can be written as the product of `x` and an independent uniformly distributed random variable `u`

```
d = Block[{y = x u}, 
   TransformedDistribution[x + y, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}], 
     u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}]}]];

PDF[d, t] // InputForm
(* Piecewise[{{Log[2]/4, t == 0}, {Log[-2/t]/4, Inequality[-2, Less, t, Less, 0]}, 
  {Log[2/t]/4, Inequality[0, Less, t, Less, 2]}}, 0] *)
```

Comment: +1.  This is short and sweet.  While the density at zero could be made to be anything non-negative in this case, why does it end up at `Log[2]/4`?  And why not have that value being $\infty$?

Comment: @JimB intriguing question.  No idea why Mathematica did that - of course the value at a set of measure 0 has no practical effect.

Comment: Your x and y are dependent., but the documentation says "TransformedDistribution[expr,{Subscript[x, 1]\[Distributed]Subscript[dist, 1],Subscript[x, 2]\[Distributed]Subscript[dist, 2] ,\[Ellipsis]}]
represents a transformed distribution where Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], \[Ellipsis] are independent and follow the distributions Subscript[dist, 1],"Subscript[dist, 2], \[Ellipsis]".

Comment: @user64494 you are correct that `x` and `y` are dependent, but note that I define the problem in terms of the random variables `x` and `u` which are independent.  The answer I obtain is essentially the same as that given by @JimB but a little shorter.

Comment: @user64494 But all three answers are the same.  They just use 3 different approaches. If a large random sample supports one answer, it supports them all.  My approach was just more brute force (following a paper and pencil) approach and the others used unknown-to-me flexibility of *Mathematica* statements and a neat observation about obtaining the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ from two independent uniform distributions.

Comment: @JimB: The statement "This becomes quite straight forward if we note that y can be written as the product of x and an independent uniformly distributed random variable u " is not grounded.